# What is the difference in behavior between ng-repeat and statically typed out code?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-model

What is the difference between the html and the behavior produced by this `ng-repeat` code:

```
        <div id="settings-row-{{key}}" class='settings-row' ng-repeat="(key, value) in items">
          <div id='settings-source-{{key}}' class='settings-source settings-column'>{{key}}</div>
          <div class='settings-slider settings-column'>
            <input type="range" ng-model="items[key]" min="0" max="4" />
          </div>
        </div>
```

and this typed out code:

```
       <div id="settings-row-science" class='settings-row'>
          <div id='settings-source-science' class='settings-source settings-column'>science</div>
          <div class='settings-slider settings-column'>
            <input type="range" ng-model="items['science']" min="0" max="4" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="settings-row-english" class='settings-row'>
          <div id='settings-source-english' class='settings-source settings-column'>english</div>
          <div class='settings-slider settings-column'>
            <input type="range" ng-model="items['english']" min="0" max="4" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="settings-row-math" class='settings-row'>
          <div id='settings-source-math' class='settings-source settings-column'>math</div>
          <div class='settings-slider settings-column'>
            <input type="range" ng-model="items['math']" min="0" max="4" />
          </div>
        </div>
```

I am trying to have the first `ng-repeat` code have the same behavior as the second typed out code, but for some reason, the first code's sliders stick and won't slide smoothly. The second code's slider slide smoothly however. What is the difference I am not accounting for? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

`items` is:

```
    {"science":0,"english":3,"math":4}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be some issue I think, anyways, to make it work try to define model as list:

```
$scope.items = [{
    "name": "science",
    "value": "0"
}, {
    "name": "english",
    "value": "3"
}, {
    "name": "math",
    "value": "4"
}];
```

where HTML is:

```
<div ng-controller="fessCntrl">
    <div id="settings-row-{{item.name}}" class='settings-row' ng-repeat="item in items">
        <div id='settings-source-{{item.name}}' class='settings-source settings-column'>{{item.name}}</div>
        <div class='settings-slider settings-column'>
            <input ng-model="item.value" type="range" min="0" max="4" />
        </div>
    </div> <pre>{{items|json}}</pre>
</div>
```

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/760/)**</kbd>

Comment: I agree, the only problem is that the api I am working with is not formatted as a list. I may just have to find an easy way to convert the object into a list (inside the angularjs controller) to support the inputs in the view and then convert the list back to the original object format (also inside the angularjs controller) when saving with an `$http.put` request.